# Symfony composite UniqueEntity constraint xml

Tags: xml, symfony, validation

I was wondering how can I specify a composite UniqueEntity constraint on an entity using xml configuration.

I know that equivalent to `@UniqueEntity(fields={"field1"})` is

```
<class name="Namespace\To\Entity">
    <constraint name="Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity">
        <option name="fields">field1</option>
        <option name="errorPath">field1</option>
        <option name="message">error.message.key</option>
    </constraint>
</class>
```

But I couldn't find how can I give the [there mentioned](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html#fields) array while on xml to achieve a `@UniqueEntity(fields={"field1, "field2"})`.

I tried various combinations, like

```
<class name="Namespace\To\Entity">
    <constraint name="Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity">
        <option name="fields">field1</option>
        <option name="fields">field2</option>
        <option name="errorPath">field1</option>
        <option name="message">error.message.key</option>
    </constraint>
</class>
```

or even

```
<class name="Namespace\To\Entity">
    <constraint name="Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity">
        <option name="fields">field1, field2</option>
        <option name="errorPath">field1</option>
        <option name="message">error.message.key</option>
    </constraint>
</class>
```

But nothing so far.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further reading, I ended up looking at the `Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Load\schema\dic\constraint-mapping\constraint-mapping-1.0.xsd` file, and there I found the answer.

If you want to have the xml equivalent to `@UniqueEntity(fields={"field1", "field2"})` you need to use the `value` element.

Here what it should be like

```
<class name="Namespace\To\Entity">
    <constraint name="Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity">
       <option name="fields">
            <value>field1</value>
            <value>field2</value>
        </option>
        <option name="errorPath">field1</option>
        <option name="message">error.message.key</option>
    </constraint>
</class>
```

Hope this post will save some time to anyone in the future.

Regards,